# Redirect 301 via htaccess with wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, user-profile

I hope I am asking this questions correctly, if I am not, please feel free to correct me.

I am trying to redirect 301 via htaccess file for all user profiles within the same site so for example. The first section shows the actual URLs I want to redirect from and to where, but this is only focused on 1 user account.

```
Redirect 301 /otsn/members/admin/my-orders/ /otsn/members/admin/shop/
```

I am thinking can I use the percentage symbol to make this redirect universal to all users, maybe I'm wrong, Can I do the following?

```
Redirect 301 /otsn/members/%/my-orders/ /otsn/members/%/shop/
```

I created a better user profile shop tab that has more capabilities, so I want to get rid of the old one and in case anyone tries to enter the old version of that profile page tab by entering the url manually, I want them sent to the new version for their profile shop page but I want this to happen with every user profile in the system.

Is this the correct method? or is there a better more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, my apologies I am fixing that. They are both in otsn directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule as **topmost rule** in your .htaccess or Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([\w-]+)/members/([\w-]+)/my-orders/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/members/%2/shop [L,R=301]
```

`%1` is back-reference for the first value we are capturing in `RewriteCond` i.e. first pattern in `(...)` and same way `%2` will represent second captured value in `(...)`.

Comment: I fixed the directory on the second set of code, it was omitted by mistake. they are both in OTSN directory. Does that change your code and how?

Comment: I have already taken care of that in my rule. Test it out as I have written and let me know.

Comment: Do I use the number after the percentage just the way you wrote it?

Comment: When I migrate the site to the root folder, will this still work? Or will I need to omit %1 ? Thank you

Comment: Yes rule will be different when used i site root .htaccess. 1st line will be: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members/([\w-]+)/my-orders/?$ [NC]` and 2nd line will be: `RewriteRule ^ /members/%1/shop [L,R=301]`

Comment: My apologies, it is redirecting me to the same page, essentially, it is refreshing the page to the same url. It is no taking me to the one I am trying to redirect the user to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203174/discussion-between-anubhava-and-rookie-recruits).